# Still Can't get LINQ Include() to Work - Despite Other Posts Explaining How

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5.0.0, and I am trying to eagerly load an Airplane's PerformancePackages when I query by TabNumber, but I cannot get it to work no matter where I put it in the query.

**Relevant code in my repository:**

```
public class ReadOnlyRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private bool disposed;
    protected DbContext context;
    protected DbQuery<T> dataset;

    public ReadOnlyRepository() : this(null) { }

    public ReadOnlyRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context ?? new MyDataContext();
        dataset = this.context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
        disposed = false;
        if (dataset.IsNull())
           throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot create dataset of type {0} from supplied context.", "context", typeof(T).Name));
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: I have, just for giggles, left off the .AsNoTracking() and it made no difference.  I didn't think it would, but I tried it anyway.

**Entity Data Model:** 
[image: Entity Data Model]

Here is the query I'm trying to get working - I'm using a Repository with the usual All() method:

```
var tabNumbers = "..." // a comma delimited string of tab numbers
var results = repo.All()
                  .Where(p => tabNumbers.ToUpper().Contains(p.TabNumber))
                  .Include(p => p.PerformancePackages)
                  .GroupBy(p => p.Model)
```

**Additional Edit:**

I have tried to simplify the query by using `.Take(10)` and leaving off the `.GroupBy()` (as well as moving the `.Include()` to before the `.Where()`) but it still returns 0 results:

```
var results = repo.All()
                  .Include(p => p.PerformancePackages)
                  .Take(10)
```

I have also tried to do it the old fashioned way with `.Include("PerformancePackages")` and that doesn't work either:

```
var results = repo.All()
                  .Include("PerformancePackages")
                  .Take(10);
```

The output I am expecting is "more than zero" performance packages (because there are no airplanes in the database without performance packages) for every airplane.  I have dummied up a counter to make it easy to see how many performance packages I'm getting back, and so far the count is always zero:

```
List<int> counter = new List<int>(results.Count());
foreach(var ap in airplanes)
{
    counter.Add(ap.PerformancePackages.Count());
}
```

Results:

```
counter[0] = 0;
counter[1] = 0;
counter[2] = 0;
counter[3] = 0;
counter[4] = 0;
counter[5] = 0;
counter[6] = 0;
counter[7] = 0;
counter[8] = 0;
counter[9] = 0;
```

Comment: Did you tried moving `Include` before `Where` call?

Comment: It's really important when asking questions to include, what the output that you expected, and what the actual output is.

Comment: show `repo.All()` implementation

Comment: I have addressed these comments in my "new and improved" posts... still no joy.

Comment: The keys that join the two tables are `Model`+`TabNumber` and at least `TabNumber` seems to be a `string`, right? Do the PK values in `Airplane` and the FK values in `PerformancePackage` match *exactly* (including casing, leading/trailing blanks, etc.)?

Comment: I figured this out - see my answer. Thanks for trying to help, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that someone was mucking around in the database and the permissions for this user to see that table somehow got "lost".  I got the permissions restored, and everything works just like you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx), when you change the shape of the data being projected to anything other than an entity, Include() will not work.

In this case, the GroupBy changes the final result to be a bunch of IGrouping, which will invalidate the above criteria. Test without the grouping and you should see it work.

Comment: I have expanded my explanation; that article was one of the first things I read, and I thought AHA! this is my problem - but I have removed the groupby and a ton of other stuff (as explained above) to no avail.